# Why i can't change the background and the text color using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

Hello i have that simple div horizonal-line-cnt that contains many items , what i want is to change the color of the cirlce in the inside and also the text color when mouse hover,  it supposed to be easy,  but i can't find what is missing,  the console is not showing any error  ,  and i tried to add an alert at the end of the function and it's doing the alert but the background of the circle is not changing and so the text color, can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
<div class="horizontal-line-cnt">
        <div class="horizontal-line"></div>
        <div class="items-cnt">
            <div class="item">
                <div class="year">
                    <p>
                        2006
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        الفكرة والتخطيط
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="year">
                    <p>
                        2006
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        الفكرة والتخطيط
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="year">
                    <p>
                        2006
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        الفكرة والتخطيط
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="item">
                <div class="year">
                    <p>
                        2006
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="circle"></div>
                <div class="text">
                    <p>
                        الفكرة والتخطيط
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the CSS:

```
`.horizontal-line-cnt {
    width: 90%;
    max-width: 1200px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

.horizontal-line {
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(230, 226, 226);
    border-radius: 2.5px;
}

.horizontal-line-cnt .items-cnt {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.horizontal-line-cnt .items-cnt .item {
    width: 25%;
    height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: -65px;
}

.item p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color:rgb(177, 175, 175);
    transition: all 0.2s;
}

.item .year p {
    color: #000;
}

.horizontal-line-cnt .item .circle {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(230, 226, 226);
    transition:all 0.2s;
    margin: 20px auto;
    z-index: 10;
}


.item .colored-circle{
    background-color: #cb8c33;
}

.black-text {
    color: #000;
}
`
```

and finally the jquery:

```
`$('.item').hover(function () {
    $(this).find($('.circle')).toggleClass('colored-circle');
    $(this).find($('.text p')).toggleClass('black-text');
    alert('finished')
})`
```

of course the problem is not in calling JQuery library bcz i have others jquery function that are working properly in the same page.

i tried to alert at the end of the function to check if the code is working 'till the end ,  and yes it's working, also i tried to alert the targted elements and it is alerting properly,  also when i check the code with devTools , the class are added normaly when mouse hover ,  but nothing is changing in the style.

Comment: It should be `$(this).find('.circle')`

Comment: yes , sure that mistake was only here,  i have updated it ,  but it is also not working

Comment: I think, both are correct, but i tried the last one you mentionned and it didn't work too, this is very weired

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS classes `.item .colored-circle` and `.black-text` are more generic than the default `.horizontal-line-cnt .item .circle` and `.item p` respectively.

You can get around this by adding !important to your CSS properties to ensure they override, or you can make your CSS classes more specific

```
.item .colored-circle { background-color: #cb8c33 !important; }
.black-text { color: #000 !important; }
```

`
OR

```
.horizontal-line-cnt .item .circle.colored-circle { background-color: #cb8c33; }
.item p.black-text { color: #000; }
```

See more about CSS specificity here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity